# /bin/sh: osascript: command not found

Tags: macos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run jupyter notebook through `Anaconda` in mac but it is showing :

```
-bash: touch: command not found
MacBook-Air:~ ajay$ /anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 1: dirname: command not found
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 3: /jupyter-notebook: No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...-bash: date: command not found
-bash: touch: command not found

...copying shared history...-bash: cp: command not found

...saving history...-bash: cat: command not found
-bash: cat: command not found
truncating history files...
...completed.
-bash: find: command not found
-bash: shlock: command not found

[Process completed]
```

The content of `jupyter_mac.command` are  :

```
DIR=$(dirname $0)
$DIR/jupyter-notebook
```

and when I run `jupyter notebook` in terminal it shows

```
/bin/sh: osascript: command not found
```

I also checked to see `jupyterlab` on `Anaconda` and it was working fine but `jupyter notebook` was not opening.

Few days ago, I installed `mongodb` on my mac and when I run `echo $PATH` it shows `/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:??`

I, even, reinstalled `anaconda` and before reinstalling deleted its folder from the drive but it still giving the same problem.

Being a new mac user, I am not able to understand what is happening, so I gave the important details.

Comment: you were double clicking `jupyter_mac.command`? if so, imho knowing the content of that script might help, you should copy paste that in here

Comment: @cryptonome Yes, i did. why what happened ?

Comment: that error message you posted is the result of that `.command` script. so in order to understand what that script did to generate the error message, you need to provide the script's content

Comment: @cryptonome updated in the question.

Comment: sorry, that seems quite straightforward to me, i don't understand why your installation path has a problem. first thing you can try is to verify your anaconda installation as described here https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/

Comment: @cryptonome only `jupyter notebook` is not working rest all other environments are working fine. I verified the installation and but everything looked fine to me.
I, even, reinstalled `anaconda` and before reinstalling deleted its folder from the drive but it still giving the same problem.

Comment: then maybe it's easier to reinstall jupyter. but i cannot advise how or if that will fix it, nor have any anaconda installed in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PATH tells the shell where to find programs. Yours is messed up, so it cannot find anything. It is probably set in `$HOME/.profile` so you need to open that file in your editor and look for `export PATH=...`.

You probably want it set something like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin
```

In future, where you add anything to your PATH, you need to carry forward whatever it was previously set to and append like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/some/new/directory
```

Once you have set your PATH correctly, start a new Terminal and run:

```
echo $PATH
```

in it to see if looks good.

Comment: I am unaware of information related to System files and all those stuff. Is there any source that I can learn about such minute details ?

Comment: This is a pretty reasonable introduction to `bash` which is what you are asking about https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Here are some Mac-specific sites depending on your level: https://www.imore.com/how-use-terminal-mac-when-you-have-no-idea-where-start  https://ss64.com/osx/

Answer (score 0):

If you did a fresh install of Anaconda on macOS Catalina, you can fix it with the following command:

```
export PATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

That worked for me, but in case this is not the correct path for you, you can run Jupiter notebook from the GUI of Anaconda navigator, and check on the terminal window that is opened automatically where is the anaconda3 folder. Then just add that to your path ;)